# regex for compare a number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex for text-box, which don't allows less than (0.5).

Is it possible with regex?

Comment: Pretty broad...Which language, which context?

Comment: its for textbox. so i think, it should be "input pattern" or "js".

Comment: You mean an HTML `input` tag?

Comment: Why try to use a regex for this? Just comparing the value will be much faster and easier: `value >= 0.5`

Comment: Regex is not a holy grail for matching....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this regex..

```
^\d*[1-9]\.{0,1}\d*|0\.{0,1}[5-9]\d*$
```

Comment: thank you so much... you are rocking... its working good... :)

Comment: Nope - This also matches strings like `32k1`

Comment: strange the \. was not copied, but converted to . - it should be like this:
^\d*[1-9]\.{0,1}\d*|0\.{0,1}[5-9]\d*$

Comment: Ah. I fixed your formatting so it shows up properly